# Qual é a forma correta de se passar os dados da view para o model?

Tags: php, laravel

Usando o Laravel, qual é a melhor forma de passar os dados da view para model? Por exemplo, dados de formulários e etc...

Há um tempo atrás, eu usava Codeigniter e enviava os dados por ajax. No caso do Laravel, seria a mesma coisa, ou tem alguma forma melhor e mais adequada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geralmente, você pode fazer o fluxo comum de um framework

- O formulário da view é submetido, os dados são processados pelo controller e daí passados para criar um model.

Um exemplo básico disso pode ser visto assim:

## View

```
{{  Form::open(['id' => 'meu-formulario']) }}
{{  Form::text('nome_produto') }}
{{  Form::submit('Enviar') }}
{{  Form::close() }}
```

## Controller

```
public function postCadastrarProduto() 
{
   $input = Input::only('nome_produto');

   Produto::create($input);
}
```

## Model

```
class Produto extends Eloquent
{
     protected $table = 'produtos';
     protected $fillable = ['nome_produto'];

}
```

Se você quiser fazer requisições ajax, você pode fazer assim:

## View

A mesma de antes

## Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/produtos/ajax-cadastrar-produto',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {nome_produto: $('#nome-produto').val()},
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
           return alert(response.error);
        }

        return alert('deu tudo certo');
    }       
});
```

## controller

```
// Se der erro, retornará um json com o índice error com alguma mensagem

public function postAjaxCadastrarProduto() 
{
   $input = Input::only('nome_produto');

   Produto::create($input);

   return Response::json(['error' => false]);
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma os dados seriam enviados sem que fizesse o reflesh na página?

Comment: Se você quiser fazer com ajax, também é possível. É bem simples.

Comment: Eu costumo usar o redirecionamento, porque no laravel é possível criar flash na sessão facilmente. Isso facilita o meu serviço ;)

Comment: Ah sim, bem interessante, não conhecia esse `Form::`

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha leve em consideração que o `Form` não é mais padrão no Laravel e só pode ser instalado a parte.

Comment: Nossa cara, muito show! ótima respota, Obrigado!